# Existing SSIS Package conversion to point to Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, data-warehouse

Migration of on-premise SSIS packages to Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Can someone suggest references or ideas/steps involved in modifying existing SSIS packages that loads a on-premise sql data warehouse to populate a SQL Data Warehouse?
Is this possible?
Regards,
KK

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to just use your existing SSIS package without changing much, it can be as simple as re-configuring the OLEDB destination to connect to Azure Data Warehouse endpoint.

But then, the right way to go about loading data to Azure DW depends on the amount of data involved and what intervals. If you are exporting large amounts of data at regular intervals, then you might want to edit your SSIS package to first stage the data in Azure blob storage flat files. Next, use execute SQL task to create external tables via Polybase and then use `CREATE TABLE AS dbo.InternalTable AS SELECT * FROM blob.ExternalTable`.

Please check [this guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-sql-server-with-integration-services) from Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

If you use the latest feature pack you can go (via blob storage) into the destination table.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt146770.aspx